# How to perform this type of MySQL query - selecting data based on 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I use PHP and I have a table named `user`.

In table `user` I have the `uid` and several other fields.
In table `data_allocate` I have `uid` and `daid`.
In table `data` I have `daid` and `data`.

What I am trying to do in one query is the following.

Select everything from `user` and for each `uid` check if `uid` exists in `data_allocate` and if it does, use the `daid` in the table to check what the matching `data` is for that `daid` in the `data` table.

An example is as follows.

**User**

```
+-----+---------+---------------------+
| uid |  name   |        email        |
+-----+---------+---------------------+
|   1 | brad    | brad@example.com    |
|   2 | simon   | simon@example.com   |
|   3 | jessica | jessica@example.com |
+-----+---------+---------------------+
```

**data_allocate**

```
+-----+------+
| uid | daid |
+-----+------+
|   1 |    2 |
|   3 |    4 |
+-----+------+
```

**data**

```
+------+----------+
| daid |   data   |
+------+----------+
|    1 | cat      |
|    2 | dog      |
|    3 | elephant |
|    4 | tiger    |
|    5 | mouse    |
+------+----------+
```

Can anybody help me build this query so it outputs as follows?

```
+------------------------------------+
|               Output               |
+------------------------------------+
| Brad   | brad@example.com  | dog   |
| Simon  | simon@example.com |       |
| Jessica|jessica@example.com| tiger |
+------------------------------------+
```

I'm guessing it's something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
JOIN data_allocate ua ON u.uid = ua.uid
JOIN data d ON u.daid = d.daid
... //then I'm stuck
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query other than the fact that you JOIN on `user_allocate` but your table is named `data_allocate`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for the pick up - edited my mistake. Just trying to work out what the rest of the query is to return the data :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the query other than the fact that you JOIN on `user_allocate` but your table is named `data_allocate`.

For your specific results, instead of targeting "*", just target the columns you want back.

```
select u.uid, u.email, d.data
    FROM user u
        JOIN data_allocate ua ON u.uid = ua.uid
        JOIN data d ON u.daid = d.daid
```

Comment: Ah! That's what I was missing!!  `select d.data` :D Thank you so much, Ohgodwhy! I can accept in 8 mins :)